# math.tan in python outputting strange values

Tags: python, math, python-turtle

```
import turtle
from tkinter import *
import math

root = Tk()

screen = turtle.Screen()

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.penup()
t.speed('fastest')

w = turtle.Turtle()
w.penup()
w.speed('fastest')
w.goto(100, 0)
w.left(90)
w.pendown()
w.forward(300)
w.back(600)
w.penup()
w.hideturtle()


def x_value(data):
    global angle
    angle = float(data)
    print(f"Angle: {angle}")
    t.setheading(angle)

x = Scale(root, from_=90, to=-90, command=x_value)
x.pack()


def intercept_finder():
    x_difference = 100-int(t.xcor())
    print(x_difference)


    #t.forward(100*math.tan(angle))
    tan_section = math.tan((angle))
    print(f"Tan_Section: {tan_section}")
    print(f"Tan: {100*tan_section}")
    print(f"X_Cord = {t.xcor()}")
    print(f"Y_Cord = {t.ycor()}")

get_x = Button(root, text='Enter', bg='red', width=5, command=intercept_finder)
get_x.pack()

screen.mainloop()
```

When angle is 50, the expected math.tan is supposed to be 119.1753593. math.tan gives me -0.27190061199763077.

I'm trying to make it so turtle finds the y cordinates it will be 100 steps more than its origina x value, so its starting cords (0,0) and the ending cord (100, ??). To find the y coordinates i need to use the formula b x tan(a), where b is the 100 steps and a is the angle.

I'm using:
b = 100
a = 50

Use these values for testing if the program outputted the correct output.

Comment: All trigonometry function in python take input in radians, not degrees. Try using `math.radians` to convert degrees to radians

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/math.html#math.tan), emphasis mine:

> `math.tan(x)`
> Return the tangent of `x` **radians**.

Meanwhile, [`setheading` uses degrees](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/turtle.html#turtle.setheading) so I'll assume your `angle` is degrees too; you'll need to convert your degrees to radians before passing to `math.tan`:

```
math.tan(math.radians(angle))
```

If you're in standard angle mode (see the `setheading` link), you shouldn't need to do any other conversion.

Comment: I'm confused, so using the logo mode will fix this issue?

Comment: No. Logo mode would mean you'd need to do something like `math.radians(-angle + 90)`. But you'll need to call `math.radians(angle)` nevertheless, because `math.tan` (and other trig functions) accept radians, not degrees.